# Trying to recreate a simple website on my local machine, but unable to do so

Tags: javascript, web, three.js

I've spent the last few hours trying to get a copy of this site (http://iacopoapps.appspot.com/hopalongwebgl/) on my local computer. I'd just like to recreate it on my machine. I've downloaded the html code from the source, the four javascript files (Three, Stats, Detector, RequestAnimationFrame) but all I see on my local machine is a black screen when I run the site.
I think I am not installing some javascript package correctly(?). But, I've copied over the contents of those four javascript files from the original website, and I'm not really sure what else to install!
Here's exactly what I did:

1. Open http://iacopoapps.appspot.com/hopalongwebgl/ Ctrl+u and copy
   all the html into my index.html
2. Notice the last  is missing, so
   I inspect element and select 'Edit as HTML' on the last div, and
   copy that over on my machine
3. Save all four javascript files
4. Run the local. See complete darkness

Comment: Probably your index.html is not correctly referencing the javascript files. Open your index.html file and see if the paths to the javascript files are correct.

Comment: it's correct. i.e. 
'<script src="three.min.js"></script>...'
and they're all in the same directory. must be something else, but have no idea what

Comment: How did you save the html? Because I was not able to.

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean. on the website, i opened up the source code (ctrl+u), saved it to my own index.html file, as i noticed in the post

Comment: Are you using Chrome? or Firefox?

Comment: You cannot use the ctrl+U option. You need to use the "Save page as..." (ctrl+S)

Comment: @gaitat, I gave that a shot just now. Same results. (just in case- i redirected the four javascripts correctly). Any other options I can try?

Comment: Use concole (F12 Crome) and check errors or missing files.